# Up to date resources/tutorials for building a Universal app?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad

I'm trying to find up to date tutorials or resources on how to build a Universal app. I'd like to know the best practices, methodologies and code.

I've previously built a few iPad apps that I'd like to refactor into iPhone apps.

The latest I've found was written last year April: http://www.kotancode.com/2011/04/05/ios-universal-apps/

Not sure if its still good? Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

There haven't been that many changes for Universal apps recently so you're not likely to find any resources with "new" information. Certain APIs are for use on the iPad only (such as SplitView) but most API methods just work across both devices.

That post seems like a fine resource. As they mention, you'll primarily test for the type of device in code using this switch: `if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad)`. Alternatively, you can check for an iPhone/iPod touch device with `UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone`. Keep in mind that these are SDK 3.2+.

Also, I recommend that you create a new universal project in Xcode and see what the defaults for a universal project are. There may be updated code that you can take advantage of since you started your project.

Answer (score 0):

I have used this documents hope it will be useful for you too.

[Universal Application](http://www.slideshare.net/cliffmcc/creating-a-universal-ios-application)